# cannot install NerdTree pluging with Vundle

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, plugin-vundle

I recently start using Vundle as plugin manager.
It nicely installed all my plugins, except NerdTree.

when trying to install `Plugin 'scroolosse/nerdTree'` 
vundle tries to connect to github, thru https, and asks me for a username and a password. I have tried providing mine but that didn't help.

For the other plugins on github, it doesn't ask for such a thing.

What is the problem ? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spelling is the issue.

```
Plugin 'scroolosse/nerdTree'
```

Should be

```
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdTree'
```

The double `s` is the clincher.

[GitHub Scrooloose NerdTree repo](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree)